# What is a good resource to learn about oriented matroids in the context of digraphs and optimization?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, matroids

I am interested in [oriented matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_matroid) in the context of directed graphs and optimization. Unfortunately, I know very little of the topic. Is there a book, article or a resource that serves as a good introduction to oriented matroids, especially in the context of directed graphs? It's a bonus if the resource is suitable for an (under)graduate level course and is preferably even free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[These notes](https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/MATHEMATIK/DMO/pubs/feu-dmo024-10.pdf) written by Winfried Hochstättler for an MAA short course on matroids look like a good, short, introduction. They also contain references to several longer references on oriented matroids.